# serial port works in debug but not release c++ code blocks windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, serial-port

I have an application which performs properly under the CodeBlocks debugger or on the release version if under the bin sub-directory of the project. If the release gets copied to anywhere else it cannot identify or open a serial port on the system. It seems like I must be missing something simple or its not linking to a `.lib` file.

I use a function to check for existing ports on the system from com1 to com20 when the program starts. Under the project directory it can be connected to a micro-controller device and communication works fine. I use this function to check each port number for existence.

```
//determine if a serial port does or does not exist
bool getComPortList(std::string portName)
{
    bool test;
    char* portNumber = new char[portName.length() + 1];
    for (unsigned int n = 0; n < portName.length(); n++)
    {
        portNumber[n] = portName[n];
    }
    HANDLE testSerial;
    testSerial = CreateFile(portNumber, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, NULL, NULL);
    if (testSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        test = false;
    }
    else
    {
        test = true;
    }
    CloseHandle(testSerial);
    delete[] portNumber;
    return test;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateFile` is called with an unterminated string. I suggest using `portName.c_str()` instead of the roll-your-own string `portNumber`.

Why?

The loop generating `portNumber` copies the characters in the string, but leaves out the terminating NULL. Odds are pretty good that debug mode politely zeroes `portNumber` when `new`ed so `portNumber` comes pre-terminated. Release mode will be compiling for speed and won't perform that which isn't explicitly requested, so no zeroing and no freebie NULL.

Why this works in one folder and not another could just be dumb unluck (Not lucky because an outright crash would be a lot easier to detect) or it could be something more sinister. Regardless, the unterminated string needs fixing.

Comment: That was definately the issue. I had caught the lack of a null in other areas where I was loading a string converted to char constant into ComboBoxes but missed it here. In those situations I added the null char manually after copying the char from the string. The `portName.c_str()` works much simpler I found.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a deployment issue - i.e. running this in the build-environment seems ok, but when you move it "outside" of the environment it does not work "stand-alone".

You can use a free tool like: [dependencywalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Run this on your executable and it will tell you what dlls/libraries you need to copy along with the program to make it run stand-alone.

It might be a bit crude, but without seeing the whole of your project environment its hard to tell what the issue is.

In some build environments (like MS visual studio) you can tell it to include all the dependencies in the executable (makes it quite big).